# APEX Aggregate Query - Query to get Sum of Amount of all opportunities of Account when stage is Closed Won

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, aggregate

I am having trouble making the query to get Sum of Amount of all opportunities of Account when stage is Closed Won. Please help me out. This is the Query I wrote.

Select SUM(AMOUNT) , ID , Name from Opportunity Group by ID,Name

But this dosent give sum of All opps related to Account it gives individual Amount of opps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gives individual amount because you're grouping by Opportunity Id, so you are not grouping at all.
You should use just `AccountId` in both SELECT and GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT AccountId, SUM(AMOUNT) total
FROM Opportunity
WHERE StageName = 'Closed Won'
GROUP BY AccountId
```

Please consider using a more selective WHERE clause: in a real life scenario you would have more than 50000 Opportunity, so you're going to hit the governor limit about SOQL Query Rows.
[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm) (emphasis mine)

> Queries that include aggregate functions are still subject to the limit on total number of query rows. **All aggregate functions** other than COUNT() or COUNT(fieldname) **include each row used by the aggregation as a query row for the purposes of limit tracking**.

Comment: Thanks Ruben. My code worked. Thanks for helping out. 
Cheers!